# Windows Service - Best practice for task scheduler

Tags: c#, .net, service

I'm looking for a bit of advice here in terms of the best way to do this. Basically I've never really created a Service application before and I've taken a shot at creating one but I feel as if the process could be improved.

One key task, yet there are a couple of tasks that are run from this service is to pulls the orders and find any that should of been delivered but haven't been marked as delivered. The service will then sends an email to the appropriate account manager. This task is run from a timer object that ticks every 15 seconds.

Now my upgrade plan is to change this so each task has it's own schedule and once it's run the services final task will be to calculate the next run time and record it, the reason being is that most of these tasks don't need to run every 15 seconds (the delayed delivery task for example only needs to run daily), yet some of them do.

The issue is that the only thing I can think of is to have a timer tick every second that looks at the schedules and if one is due, run it. If not do nothing. Is this a tidy way of approaching this task or can anyone think of a better way to do this?